# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

On a React page called `Checkout`, I have the following code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let { org } = this.state;
    const data = { organisation: org };
    this.props.checkout_payment(data);
}
```

This refers to a Redux method:

```
export const checkout_payment = async (data) => {
    let token = getAuthToken();
    const body = data;
    try {
        let result = await axios.post(`${url}/checkout_payment`, body, {
            headers: { Authorization: `${token}` },
        });
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response === undefined) {
            Notification({ message: error.message, success: false });
        } else {
            Notification({ message: error.response.data, success: false });
        }
    }
}
```

When the code reached the `try` block from the Redux method, I get the error below. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
The above error occurred in the <Checkout> component:
    in Checkout (created by Connect(Checkout))
    in Connect(Checkout) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(Connect(Checkout)) (at pages/index.js:240)
    in Route (at pages/index.js:236)
    in PrivateRoute (at pages/index.js:437)
    in Switch (at pages/index.js:320)
    in Router (at pages/index.js:319)
    in div (at pages/index.js:318)
    in Base (created by Connect(Base))
    in Connect(Base) (at src/index.js:91)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:90)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:89)
```

I've also tried to replace the `try` code block with the code below, but that made no difference.

```
return (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .post(`${url}/checkout_payment`, body, { headers: { Authorization: `${token}` } })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err.response === undefined) {
                Notification({ message: err.message, success: false });
            } else {
                return dispatch({ type: PAYMENT_ERROR, payload: err.response.data });
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your reducer function should not have any side effects such as async code, HTTP requests, reading/writing to local storage etc.
So you have to use the middleware concept to make all this async.
To use middleware, you need to configure your store.
Please check [docs](https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/middleware#the-final-approach)

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(middleware1, middleware2)
)
```

Comment: Any idea what this code should be when using `redux-thunk`? I haven't written the app that I'm working with myself, but redux-thunk is already configured for the app. I'm not a programmer and don't understand the docs.

Comment: If thunk already configured, then it should be added to your store configuration like below, `applyMiddleware(thunk)` then you can create an action. You can check this [doc](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/redux-thunk-explained-with-examples/). Probably, if you have already configured redux-thunk, you can try to find examples in your existing actions